# neither user or current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH

Tags: android, adt

I have a simple app that so far just turns bluetooth on/off, when i run it on emulator or on a nexus 7 it says my app has stopped responding and then closes itself upon launch.
I tried adding an onStart() method since that fixed this issue in a similar question, adding the intent that gets users permission and switching around various things to different methods, still crashing however.

Logcat has these messages:

```
07-29 01:05:41.541: E/AndroidRuntime(9745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 01:05:41.541: E/AndroidRuntime(9745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackagename/mmypackagename.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10067 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackagename"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BlUETOOTH"/>
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="5"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/homeiconsmall"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
                android:launchMode="singleTask" 
                android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled the permission in your manifest (`BlUE` != `BLUE`):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BlUETOOTH"/>
```